# Why does Python's urllib.request.urlopen send POST data as query string?

Tags: python, curl, post, solr, urllib

`curl` correctly posts data to Solr:

```
$ curl -v 'http://solr.example.no:12699/solr/my_coll/update?commit=true' \
--data '<add><doc><field name="key">KEY__9927.1</field><field name="value">\
{"result":0,"jobId":"9459695","jobNumber":"9927.1"}</field></doc></add>'
```

The solr query log says:

```
[20200306T111354,131] [my_coll_shard1_replica_n85]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={commit=true} status=0 QTime=96
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with Python:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> data = '<add><doc><field name="key">KEY__9927.1</field><field name="value">{"result":0,"jobId":"9459695","jobNumber":"9927.1"}</field></doc></add>'
>>> url = 'http://solr.example.no:12699/solr/my_coll/update?commit=true'
>>> req = urllib.request.Request(url=url, data=data.encode('utf-8'), method='POST')
>>> res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

But now the solr query log shows that the POST data has been added to the query param string:

```
[20200306T112358,780] [my_coll_shard1_replica_n87]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={commit=true&<add><doc><field+name="key">KEY__9927.1</field><field+name%3D"value">{"result":0,"jobId":"9459695","jobNumber":"9927.1"}</field></doc></add>} status=0 QTime=30
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're not sending the correct Content-Type for your request, and this gets mangled within Jetty (or the Solr app) before being forwarded to the log (any POSTed data that's not multipart can be inserted as part of the query string - Solr parses them all the same). The `/update` endpoint accepts multiple formats, such as both JSON and XML, and the Content-Type should be set appropriately.

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url=url, data=data.encode('utf-8'), method='POST', headers={'Content-Type': 'text/xml'})
res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

In fact, it's the `User-Agent` string that changes the behaviour. This is by design - `curl` has been special cased to override the default `Content-Type` handler. If you're not using `curl`, you have to explicitly provide the `Content-Type` being submitted. This has probably been done to make it easier to make manual requests using `curl` on the command line. The implementation is available in [SolrRequestParsers.java, line 782](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/40661489cd590947f513e553a20707d0c82b82e5/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/servlet/SolrRequestParsers.java#L782)

Comment: As you see in the wireshark output in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571172/13365), the `Content-Type` is actually set automatically. In the working `curl` case, `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` works just fine.

Comment: Yap, but setting `Connection: close` with curl doesn't change anything either, so that's not the case. Regardless, setting the correct Content-Type (since what you're submitting is _not_ `x-www-form-urlencoded`) makes everything behave as it should.

Comment: In fact, it's the `User-Agent` string that changes the behaviour. This is by design - `curl` has been special cased to override the default Content-Type handler. If you're not using curl, you have to explicitly provide the Content-Type being submitted. This has probably been done to make it easier to make manual requests using `curl` on the command line. The implementation is available in [SolrRequestParsers.java, Line 782](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/40661489cd590947f513e553a20707d0c82b82e5/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/servlet/SolrRequestParsers.java#L782)

Comment: Wow, great find! "Interesting" implementation by Solr :D